# Error while performing circular crop

Tags: matlab

On running this code I get an error saying:

> > Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in crop (line 8)
>
> croppedImage(:,:,2)=I(:,:,2).*mask;

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
imageSize = size(I);
ci = [100,100,20];     % center and radius of circle ([c_row, c_col, r])
[xx,yy] = ndgrid((1:imageSize(1))-ci(1),(1:imageSize(2))-ci(2));
mask = uint8((xx.^2 + yy.^2)<ci(3)^2);
croppedImage = uint8(zeros(size(I))); 
croppedImage(:,:,1)=I(:,:,1).*mask;
croppedImage(:,:,2)=I(:,:,2).*mask;
croppedImage(:,:,3)=I(:,:,3).*mask;
imshow(croppedImage);
```

Please Help as I'm unable to debug this error.

Comment: Doesn't look like C code?

Comment: matlab, probably?

Comment: because..... it is not a RGB image, but a grayscale image?.....

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
croppedImage(:,:,1)=I(:,:,1).*mask;
croppedImage(:,:,2)=I(:,:,2).*mask;
croppedImage(:,:,3)=I(:,:,3).*mask;
```

by

```
croppedImage=bsxfun(@times,I,mask);
```

This will make sure that the mask is applied whether `I` is grayscale or RGB

Comment: Thank you so much for the help,

Comment: @Shirley Consider accepting the answer if it helped